# Spans don't close a modal on click despite they can send logs etc

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating modals for a study project website. There are several cards, each of them open different modals on click and there is no problem with that.

When I click outside `modal_content` it works perfectly, but not `span` elements.

Here is my code. I know it's pretty messy, sorry for that. Could you please help me to figure out the problem? I expected the spans to close my modals on click, but it doesn't happen.

```js
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("card_modal");
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("closeDiv");

for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
      console.log(i, modals[i].style.display)
      modals[i].style.display = "none";
      console.log(i, modals[i].style.display)
    }
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].onclick = function() {
    modals[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    if (event.target == modals[i]) {
      modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_top">
    <a class="card_image" href="#"> <img src="img/LOGO.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card_bottom">
    <a href="" class="card_title">"x" Type beat</a>
    <div class="card_prices">
      <div class="card_price">1500</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_modal">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <span class="closeDiv">&times;</span>
      <p>modal 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_top">
    <a class="card_image" href="#"> <img src="img/LOGO.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card_bottom">
    <a href="" class="card_title">"x" Type beat</a>
    <div class="card_prices">
      <div class="card_price">1500</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_modal">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <span class="closeDiv">&times;</span>
      <p>modal 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I even tried to put a cycle in a cycle in order to change the display property to none of all modals, but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the click event on the `span` element is propagating up to the `window`, so the click is being caught by two separate event handlers which show/hide it, so nothing appears to happen.

To fix the problem you can call `stopPropagation()` on the Event object which fires when the `span` is clicked:

```js
spans[i].onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // your code...
}
```

Here's a full working version:

```js
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("card_modal");
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("closeDiv");

for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
      modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].onclick = function() {
    modals[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    if (event.target == modals[i]) {
      modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.card_modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_top">
    <a class="card_image" href="#"> <img src="img/LOGO.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card_bottom">
    <a href="" class="card_title">"x" Type beat</a>
    <div class="card_prices">
      <div class="card_price">1500</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_modal">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <span class="closeDiv">&times;</span>
      <p>modal 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_top">
    <a class="card_image" href="#"> <img src="img/LOGO.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card_bottom">
    <a href="" class="card_title">"x" Type beat</a>
    <div class="card_prices">
      <div class="card_price">1500</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_modal">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <span class="closeDiv">&times;</span>
      <p>modal 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said your code can be improved by using CSS classes which you add/remove to show/hide the modals, and also by using DOM traversal methods to relate the elements to each other instead of an arbitrary index. Here's an updated working version:

```js
const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".card_modal");
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".closeDiv");

// Show the related modal when clicking on the card
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('click', () => {
    card.querySelector('.card_modal').classList.add('show');
  });
});

// Hide the related modal when clicking the X span
spans.forEach(span => {
  span.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    span.closest('.card').querySelector('.card_modal').classList.remove('show');
  }); 
});

// Hide all modals when clicking out side a modal
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!e.target.closest('.card')) {
    modals.forEach(modal => modal.classList.remove('show'));
  }
})
```

```css
.card_modal {
  display: none;
}

.card_modal.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_top">
    <a class="card_image" href="#"> <img src="img/LOGO.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card_bottom">
    <a href="" class="card_title">"x" Type beat</a>
    <div class="card_prices">
      <div class="card_price">1500</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_modal">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <span class="closeDiv">&times;</span>
      <p>modal 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_top">
    <a class="card_image" href="#"> <img src="img/LOGO.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card_bottom">
    <a href="" class="card_title">"x" Type beat</a>
    <div class="card_prices">
      <div class="card_price">1500</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_modal">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <span class="closeDiv">&times;</span>
      <p>modal 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for such a detailed reply. Your solution works perfectly! I'll also study your advice on using CSS classes and DOM methods. I am not familiar with these methods yet, so I have a lot to learn. Thanks!!